# attempting to loop through images to save and record each indivdually

Tags: php, image-processing, pdo, foreach

I am working on a method that saves and records the images that users select and post.

Heres my method.

```
public function setEventImages($event_id){
            foreach($_FILES['event-images']['tmp_name'] as $tmp_name){ 
                var_dump($imgName = $this->imgPath . $this->random_name . $_FILES['event-images']['name']);
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $imgName);
                $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name (event_image_name, event_id) VALUES (?,?)");
                $stmt->bindParam(1, $imgName, PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindValue(2, $event_id, PARAM_INT);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
        }
```

Am I actually looping through each image correctly by referencing `['tmp_name']` in the `foreach()` loop?

The `var_dump()` returns:

> string(38) "img/event-images/9596177294458547Array"

Why is it not displaying the name of each file?

Comment: Why are you preparing new statement and bind new variables on every round of the loop?

Answer (score 2):

> Am I actually looping through each image correctly by referencing ['tmp_name'] in the foreach() loop?

The answer to your question is No

Assuming you have your file inputs in your form as

```
<input type="file" name="event-images[]" />
<input type="file" name="event-images[]" />
<input type="file" name="event-images[]" />
```

Then upon submitting the form the PHP script will receive an `array() $_FILES`, if you `var_dump()` that you can see it contains another `array() $_FILES['event-image']`

Therefore if you loop through `$_FILES['event-images']`

```
foreach($_FILES['event-images'] as $file)
{
    var_dump($file);
}
```

You will see that `$file` is an `array()`, and one of its key/value pairs is `tmp_name => tmp_name_assigned_by_server` another one will be `name => original_file_name`

Look here for examples and reference
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, i think this part:

```
var_dump($imgName = $this->imgPath . $this->random_name . $_FILES['event-images']['name']);
```

should be

```
 var_dump($imgName = $this->imgPath . $this->random_name . $tmp_name);
```

as you assign to $tmp_name every single value of the array with foreach, but as you are doing, you are inserthing the whole array.

Comment: I want to add on the end the name of this current image, not the tmp directory.